# Why AWS Cloudfront not classifying Tablet device as Tablet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway

Below is the Lambda code I have.

When I hit the lambda, I could either get 'Desktop' or 'Mobile'. When I send a Tablet UserAgent, it is not classifying it as Tablet.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var region = process.env.AWS_REGION ? process.env.AWS_REGION : 'us-east-1';
    console.log(region);
    console.log(event);

    var device = {};
    if( event.headers['CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer']  === "true" )
         device.device = 'Mobile';
    else if ( event.headers['CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer']  === "true" )
         device.device = 'Tablet';
     else
         device.device = 'Desktop';

     var response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(device)
    };

    callback(null, response);
};
```

I did double checked the headers received to lambda as well.

```
'CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer': 'true',
'CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer': 'false',
'CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer': 'false',
'CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer': 'false',
'CloudFront-Viewer-Country': 'US',
```

**User-Agent:**

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B410 Safari/600.1.4

Comment: I can't explain "desktop" here but your test needs to be in this order: SmartTV (optional) then Tablet then Mobile then Desktop... because the categorizations are not mutually-exclusive.  You can, and will, for example, see Is-Tablet-Viewer and Is-Mobile-Viewer **both** set to true, with a tablet, so you can't test mobile first and get the right answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Based on the value of the User-Agent header, CloudFront sets the value of these headers to true or false before forwarding the request to your origin. **If a device falls into more than one category, more than one value might be true.** For example, for some tablet devices, CloudFront might set both CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer and CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer to true. *(emphasis added)*
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html#header-caching-web-device

So if you are down-converting these to a single device categorization, you are likely to get the most sensible result if you test them in this order, stopping on the first match:

```
CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer
CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer
CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer
CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer
```

Comment: That isn't answering the question at all. The question is why isn't "ipad" marking Tablet = true